# Dropdown menu in google maps info window

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a dropdown menu that I want to put inside a google maps infowindow. The menu is populated with contents from an array. When I position the menu outside the info window it works fine but when I try and put it inside the infowindow it breaks. The end goal is to get a form inside the info window so when I submit the form I can process the form data and return the directions to the marker. I have attached the code below and the problematic line is denoted by ** and thanks in advance for all your help.

Infowindow code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
    var locationofplace = place.geometry.location;
    var markerlocation = marker.getPosition();
    var markerlat = markerlocation.lat();
    var markerlng = markerlocation.lng();

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var contentStr = '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5><p>' + place.formatted_address;
      if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>' + place.formatted_phone_number;
      if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a>'; * * contentStr += '<form><select id="selectNumber"><option>Change Address</option></select></form>'; * *
        contentStr += '<br><a href="javascript:calcRoute(0,' + markerlat + ',' + markerlng + ');">Get Directions</a>';

      contentStr += '<br>' + place.types + '</p>';

      infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    } else {
      var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
      infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });

});
```

add data to menu code:

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {
  var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

  for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    var opt = addresses[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `domready`-event of the `infowindow` instead of the `load`-event of the `window` to manipulate the dropdown(the dropdown hasn't been injected into the document before the domready-event)